# Location of non-exported header files?

Tags: ros, c++, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a package which is only building a binary and not exporting libraries, should the headers still go in `include/pkgname`, or can/should they then go in `src`? The [Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#Common_Files_and_Directories) page says:

> `include/package_name`: C++ include headers (make sure to export in the CMakeLists.txt)

My [um6 sensor driver](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/um6) has them split, while [rosserial_server](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/tree/hydro-devel/rosserial_server/src) has them all together.

In both cases, there are templated classes in the headers, which means they contain a lot of actual function bodies. Should these headers be exported anyway, despite that they're not intended to be an API? Which approach is best?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131601/location-of-non-exported-header-files?/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's best to keep the headers in the include directory so that you always look in the same place. Just don't make the installation rule for the headers and don't add the include dir to the catkin_package call so they aren't exported. If things are not expected to be an API they shouldn't be exposed if possible.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2014-02-21**:
Cool, sounds good. I'll reorganize rosserial_server when I get a chance.